# ElasticSearch non-duplicates finder query

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I want to count the amount of files with unique field "url" within my dataset.
Currently I tried this query:

```
search_query = { 
  "aggs": {
    "agg-test": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "url"
      }
    }
  }
}

search_results = es.search(index='poc', query=search_query)
hits = search_results["hits"]["hits"]
db = list(hits)
len(db)
```

But I get the error:

> BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'unknown query [aggs]')

What's the problem and how can I solve?